# How to make new groups immediately visible in a new mailing?

Tags: civimail

It seems that a newly created group (with mailinglist checked) isn't directly available when sending a new mass mailing, but does eventually end up being visible after a few minutes (probably between 5 and 10 min?)

This happen with the "new" angular interface, we didn't have this issue with the previous interface.

Are the list of available groups cached somewhere? Is there a way to clear that cache (or submit a PR so it does it by default after creating a mailing list group)?

Comment: I just tried this on [dmaster](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/) and the group was directly available within next load of New Mailing Page after creating the group. I don't think it may be a cache issue as the group list are retrieved by calling the group `get` api.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I wonder what in my config makes it cached for a while.